# Getting PageParameters from another Page

Tags: java, web-applications, wicket, parameter-passing

I want to get a parameter from another page to mount an ImageResourceReference. 
How could I make that?

```
public MyApp extends WebApp {

    public init() {
        .....
        .....
        mountPage("/edit/book/ref/${ref_number}", EditBookPage.class);
        mountResource("/book/ref_nr/${ref_number}/${name}", new ImageResourceReference());
    }
}
```

the **${name}** is defined in the ImageResourceReference.java, so there is no problem with it.
But I would like to get the **${ref_number}**, but don t know how to make that..

**${ref_number}** is a parameter of EditBookPage

Comment: anyone could help? thx!

Comment: The ref_number should be accessible exactly the same as the name. Please explain why you can't access the ref_number (errors, exception stack traces and the like would be helpfull).

Comment: @Nicktar I need it by "mountResource"-Method. I could get it by mountPage without problems.

There wasn't any exceptions/errors or sthing like that. But by mountResource it was ignored with the actual implementation (above). When I click on the link, I get a link looking like this:
`http://localhost:8080/book_collection/book/ref_nr//IMAGE_NAME_HERE.jpg`
between the **//** should be the parameter ${ref_number} actually, but it is ignored by the mountResource method as I see..

Comment: and i cant accept answers that wasn't the right ones :-)

Comment: Is my question not so clear/precise?

Comment: If you're not getting the right andswers to about 70% of your questions, thetn why do you keep coming back?

Comment: @Nicktar what could be an answer to the actual question? :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47427/discussion-between-zelelb-and-nicktar)

Comment: If you have ref_number in ImageResourceReference, just get it from there before mounting the resource!?

Comment: @pikand no I don't.. that's why! 'ref_number' is in EditBookPage

Comment: any solutioon for that?

Comment: EditBookPage could add the image reference